# Problem when installing pear packages for php

Tags: 11.04, php

When trying to install pear packages I get the following error:

```
sudo pear install validate
[sudo] password for nicolas: 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PEAR::raiseErro() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 165
```

This `PEAR::raiseErro()` seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/774452.
That page says it's fixed now (since 11 hours), so it should be fixed in the next update of the php-pear package. The bug report also has a pointer to the related bug report in Debian, which points to the [upstream diff](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/pear-core/trunk/PEAR/REST.php?r1=308688&r2=308983).

Comment: Excellent news! It was blocking me a bunch. Thanks for the info.